# deeplearning and deepwater models give very different logloss (0.4 vs 0.6)

Tags: h2o

In AWS, I followed the instruction in [here](https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater#pre-release-amazon-aws-image) and launched a g2.2xlarge EC2 using the community AMI ami-97591381 (h2o version: 3.13.0.356).

This is my code, which you can run as I made the S3 links public:

```
library(h2o)
library(jsonlite)
library(curl)

localH2O = h2o.init()

df.truth <- h2o.importFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nw.data.test.us.east/df.truth.zeroed", header = T, sep=",")
df.truth$isFemale <- h2o.asfactor(df.truth$isFemale)
hotnames.truth <- fromJSON("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nw.data.test.us.east/hotnames.json", simplifyVector = T)

# Training and validation sets
splits <- h2o.splitFrame(df.truth, c(0.9), seed=1234)
train.truth <- h2o.assign(splits[[1]], "train.truth.hex")   
valid.truth <- h2o.assign(splits[[2]], "valid.truth.hex")

# Train a model using non-GPU deeplearning
dl.2 <- h2o.deeplearning(         
  training_frame = train.truth, model_id="dl.2",
  validation_frame = valid.truth,      
  x=setdiff(hotnames.truth[1:(length(hotnames.truth)/2)], c("isFemale", "nwtcs")),
  y="isFemale", stopping_metric = "AUTO", seed = 1,
  sparse = F, mini_batch_size = 20)

# Train a model using GPU-enabled deepwater
dw.2 <- h2o.deepwater(         
  training_frame = train.truth, model_id="dw.2", 
  validation_frame = valid.truth,         
  x=setdiff(hotnames.truth[1:(length(hotnames.truth)/2)], c("isFemale", "nwtcs")),
  y="isFemale", stopping_metric = "AUTO", seed = 1,
  sparse = F, mini_batch_size = 20)
```

When I inspect the two models, to my surprise I saw **large** difference in logloss:

## Non-GPU

```
print(dl.2)
Model Details:
==============

H2OBinomialModel: deeplearning
Model ID:  dl.2
Status of Neuron Layers: predicting isFemale, 2-class classification, bernoulli distribution, CrossEntropy loss, 160,802 weights/biases, 2.0 MB, 1,041,465 training samples, mini-batch size 1
  layer units      type dropout       l1       l2 mean_rate rate_rms momentum
1     1   600     Input  0.00 %
2     2   200 Rectifier  0.00 % 0.000000 0.000000  0.104435 0.102760 0.000000
3     3   200 Rectifier  0.00 % 0.000000 0.000000  0.031395 0.055490 0.000000
4     4     2   Softmax         0.000000 0.000000  0.001541 0.001438 0.000000
  mean_weight weight_rms mean_bias bias_rms
1
2    0.018904   0.144034  0.150630 0.415525
3   -0.023333   0.081914  0.545394 0.251275
4    0.029091   0.295439 -0.004396 0.357609

H2OBinomialMetrics: deeplearning
** Reported on training data. **
** Metrics reported on temporary training frame with 9877 samples **

MSE:  0.1213733
RMSE:  0.3483868
LogLoss:  0.388214
Mean Per-Class Error:  0.2563669
AUC:  0.8433182
Gini:  0.6866365

Confusion Matrix (vertical: actual; across: predicted) for F1-optimal threshold:
          0    1    Error        Rate
0      6546 1079 0.141508  =1079/7625
1       836 1416 0.371226   =836/2252
Totals 7382 2495 0.193885  =1915/9877

H2OBinomialMetrics: deeplearning
** Reported on validation data. **
** Metrics reported on full validation frame **

MSE:  0.126671
RMSE:  0.3559087
LogLoss:  0.4005941
Mean Per-Class Error:  0.2585051
AUC:  0.8309913
Gini:  0.6619825

Confusion Matrix (vertical: actual; across: predicted) for F1-optimal threshold:
           0    1    Error         Rate
0      11746 3134 0.210618  =3134/14880
1       1323 2995 0.306392   =1323/4318
Totals 13069 6129 0.232160  =4457/19198
```

## GPU-enabled

```
print(dw.2)
Model Details:
==============

H2OBinomialModel: deepwater
Model ID:  dw.2b
Status of Deep Learning Model: MLP: [200, 200], 630.8 KB, predicting isFemale, 2-class classification, 1,708,160 training samples, mini-batch size 20
  input_neurons     rate momentum
1           600 0.000369 0.900000


H2OBinomialMetrics: deepwater
** Reported on training data. **
** Metrics reported on temporary training frame with 9877 samples **

MSE:  0.1615781
RMSE:  0.4019677
LogLoss:  0.629549
Mean Per-Class Error:  0.3467246
AUC:  0.7289561
Gini:  0.4579122

Confusion Matrix (vertical: actual; across: predicted) for F1-optimal threshold:
          0    1    Error        Rate
0      4843 2782 0.364852  =2782/7625
1       740 1512 0.328597   =740/2252
Totals 5583 4294 0.356586  =3522/9877

H2OBinomialMetrics: deepwater
** Reported on validation data. **
** Metrics reported on full validation frame **

MSE:  0.1651776
RMSE:  0.4064205
LogLoss:  0.6901861
Mean Per-Class Error:  0.3476629
AUC:  0.7187362
Gini:  0.4374724

Confusion Matrix (vertical: actual; across: predicted) for F1-optimal threshold:
          0    1    Error         Rate
0      8624 6256 0.420430  =6256/14880
1      1187 3131 0.274896   =1187/4318
Totals 9811 9387 0.387697  =7443/19198
```

As seen above, the difference in logloss is huge between non-GPU and GPU models:

```
Logloss
+----------------------------------+
|                 | non-GPU | GPU  |
+----------------------------------+
| training data   | 0.39    | 0.63 |
+----------------------------------|
| validation data | 0.40    | 0.69 |
+----------------------------------+
```

I understand that due to the stochastic nature of the training I will get different results, but I won't expect such a huge difference between non-GPU and GPU.

Answer (score 1):

`h2o.deeplearning` is H2O's built-in deep-learning algorithm. It parallelizes very well, works well with large data, but does not use GPUs.

`h2o.deepwater` is a wrapper around (probably) Tensorflow, and (probably) using your GPU (but it can use the CPU, and it can use different back-ends).

In other words, this is not a difference in using the CPU or using the GPU: you are using two different implementations of deep learning.

BTW, I'd suggest you increase the number of `epochs` (from the default of 10, to something like 200 - bearing in mind this means it will take 20x longer to run), and see if the difference is still there. Or compare the score history charts, and see if Tensorflow is getting there, but just needs, say, 50% more epochs to get the same logloss score.

Comment: I originally thought that since `h2o.deeplearning` and `h2o.deepwater` are constructing _similar_ networks (_similar_ in terms of no. of layers, nodes, activation function, etc), they will produce similar results.  I think my assumption is wrong.  Thanks for your suggestion and I will try increasing the epochs.